# Python Pandas: LabelEncoding fitting unknown variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, encoding, sklearn-pandas

- Hi I have a dataframe full of strings and I want to encode these strings and store their corresponding codes.
- I want to produce these codes on one column and fit onto another column.
- When I fit these codes on some other column that has a string that I haven't seen on my training column I want to create another unique value for that.
- I have tried LabelEncoding function but it gives error on the previously unseen strings.

For example a have dataframe:

```
 col1  col2
  a     a
  b     b
  c     e
  d     f
```

After training LabelEncoding on first column I get something like this:

```
 col1  col2
  1     a
  2     b
  3     e
  4     f
```

After fitting on the created codes onthe second column I want to have something like this:

```
 col1  col2
  1     1
  2     2
  3     5
  4     6
```

What is the easiest way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Created `df` dataframe by copying sample from OP's post as follows.

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
```

Its value will be as follows when we print it:

```
    col1    col2
0    a       a 
1    b       b 
2    c       e 
3    d       f
```

Could you please try following. I have given here only 1st 6 alphabets you could mention all in case you have them in your actual Input_file.

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
df.applymap(lambda s: dict1.get(s) if s in dict1 else s)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
   col1   col2
0   1      1 
1   2      2 
2   3      5 
3   4      6
```

Comment: I dont know actually e and f previously I want to assign them a code as  I see them at the first time.

Comment: @s900n, sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain it more here.

Answer (score 0):

You could encoding yourself using `pd.factorize`:

```
v, k = pd.factorize(sorted(df.stack().unique()))

m = dict(zip(k.tolist(), (v+1).tolist()))

df.replace(m)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     3     5
3     4     6
```

I think the real trick is to stack col1 and col2 then encoding the values of both list as one.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.stack())
```